# Смена цвета кнопки через js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть кнопка, она стилизована через `css`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Перевести" title="Перевести">
```

Есть файл `config.js` Хочется сделать так, чтобы в данном файле я вводил цвет кнопки(например создать переменную, если так можно), и после подключения данного конфига к странице, цвет кнопки менялся на введенный в данный конфиг.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то вроде так:

```js
var color = 'green'; // Либо hex #fafafa и т.д.

// Менять цвет при клике, либо сразу после загрузки dom
function change(identifier) {
 identifier.style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change(this)" type="submit" value="Перевести" title="Перевести">
```

**P.S.** *Помимо самого способа решения, суть вопроса в том, чтобы [стилям кнопки указать переменную](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes) со цветом.*

Comment: А если мне надо сделать конфиг отдельно, а саму реализацию кода в другом файле. т.е. в config.js я ввожу цвет в переменную color. А в файле main.js я обращаюсь к данной переменной и соответственно меняю цвет элемента через функцию. Например     const color = require('./config.js)'. Так можно, или выглядит странно?

Comment: @Neykoqt, если Вы подключите `config.js` ранее, чем например `main.js`, то переменная `color` у Вас будет определена и ничего в `main.js` указывать не надо. Но мне кажется, что так не стоит делать, т.к. в `main.js` может быть переменная с таким же именем и код пойдёт по швам..

Comment: А как тогда лучше поступить, чтобы заданный конфиг был отдельно от реализации?

Comment: @Neykoqt, это уже от структуры самого проекта зависит. Возможно лучше `main.js` подключать сразу после конфига..